# Android - Un-erasable application

Tags: android

Is it possible to make my application "un-erasable"? By that I mean a lot of things...

1-Cannot be uninstalled unless the user enters a password for example.
2-If the user restores factory settings then my application and its data won't be deleted.
3-User cannot kill the application; as in force it to end while it's running.

*Note: Sometimes this can be beneficial to the user. In my application, my client almost necessitates such an option to exist.

Comment: This would be such a terrible idea if it were possible.  Just think of the possibilities for malware if you could keep an application from being installed.  Also, the concept of having an application survive a factory reset is just silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of making an app uninstallable is getting it baked into the firmware of the handset before its launch. This is usually done by having a tie-up with the wireless carrier, who requires the app to be preloaded by the OEM. But for normal apps delivered through Android Marketplace it is not possible.

Answer (score 9):

## No

Answer (score 2):

[Here's what you're looking for.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware)

<sup>No, it's not possible. That would be terribly unfriendly to the user.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Even the apps which comes with system images, >> i mean which comes preinstalled, can be killed by os when it need resources. But user can not erase system apps, So if you want to have your app permanently, start selling you own phone with yours OS in it, with your app isbuilt with os.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you need root and chmod your app to 0000
or just put the apk in /system/ partition